# Many networked arduinos getting delayed messages

Tags: networking, websocket, arduino

We have a system of 10 networked Arduinos with ethershields. All arduinos are hooked to a node server via websockets.

Every second the node server sends a message to all ardunios with the current time. The ardunios receive the message and display on an attached LCD.

The problem is that they are not in sync. When we only have 2 arduinos everything works fine but when that number is closer to 10 the timing of the messages received quickly get to be off by as many as 10 seconds.

Has anyone seen anything similar?

Comment: Can you give an example of the code you're using, both for the node.js server and for the Arduino clients?

Comment: @duskwuff sure, the websocket is pretty simple on the node server:
https://gist.github.com/bcardarella/dc4d52f713503d194edf

For the arduinos it simply receives the message and displays it.